# Запятые в предложении "...отучить его от привычки(,) доев свое жаркое(,) вытирать тарелку хлебом"

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Встретилась такая фраза:

> Эми, например, стоило большого труда отучить его от привычки(,) доев свое  жаркое
>   с подливкой(,) вытирать тарелку хлебом и съедать его.

Запятые, которые у меня в скобках, **были**. Вообще фраза кривоватая, но тем не менее хочется понять, *действительно ли нужны эти запятые.*

Что я думаю? Первую запятую совсем не хочется ставить, п. ч. идёт пояснение, что за привычка. А разбивать наименование привычки на части может затруднить понимание, что к чему относится в предложении и того, что это и есть описание привычки. Однако это всё же деепричастный оборот...

Answer (score 2):

Эми, например, стоило большого труда отучить его от привычки, доев свое жаркое с подливкой, вытирать тарелку хлебом и съедать его (Сомерсет Моэм).

Конечно, **деепричастные обороты по правилу должны обособляться**, но только вот  инфинитивные определения (тоже по правилу)   должны **следовать за определяемым словом,**  (1) образуя словосочетание (Нужно иметь **мужество признать** и свою неудачу), или (2) могут обособляться с помощью тире (Почему бы вам не задаться  очень важной **целью — сэкономить** выделенные средства).

Итак, инфинитивные определения в современной книжной речи **не располагаются на расстоянии от определяемого существительного**, как это допускалось, возможно, в старой грамматике.

В разговорном стиле  возможен такой вариант: У него  привычка: взяв книгу, ее не возвращать. Но и здесь нужна пауза, двоеточие на письме.

**Возможное редактирование предложения**: Эми, например, стоило большого труда отучить его **от такОй привычки**: доев свое жаркое с подливкой, вытирать тарелку хлебом и съедать его .

[§ 60. Знаки препинания при обособленных несогласованных определениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=155)

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла!

Answer (score 0):

Моё мнение такое, что данный деепричастный оборот (со значением обстоятельства образа действий) не должен обособляться на письме, потому что это — именно тот случай, когда сказуемое неразрывно связано с деепричастным оборотом и образует смысловой центр высказывания.

Если убрать "доев своё жаркое с подливкой", то смысл предложения в корне меняется на просто "вытирать тарелку хлебом и съедать его".

Comment: Смысл-то как раз не меняется!)

Comment: Если бы это было ваше предложение, то, вам, наверное, было бы видней, но мы исходим из того, что предложение не ваше :)) С моей точки зрения, смысл как раз меняется, потому что я вижу это так, что старание отучить направлено к привычке вытирать тарелку хлебом именно после жаркого. Из данного предложения не ясно, стала бы она его отучивать, если бы он вытирал тарелку после другого блюда. (теория и примеры: http://bit.ly/2mAEXXQ)

Comment: Ну если именно после жаркого, тогда действительно смысл теряется. Я, видимо, не понимаю просто, почему это принципиально.)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вы не в том направлении рассуждаете. Теряется смысл или нет (он не теряется, конечно), но это не причина отказываться от запятой. Для отказа от запятой по мотивам "обстоятельственного значения" должно присутствовать действительно сильное, неоспоримое "наречное"  значение, неотрывное от связанного глагола. Во нашей же фразе действия  по деепричастию "доев" и "вытирать" разнесены не только по смыслу, но и по времени, трактовка как обстоятельства исключена полностью.  А уж про "образ действия" тут вообще ничего не напоминает.

Comment: Да это не я рассуждал на эту тему.)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Я понял, кто рассуждал. Я вот на это ответил "Я, видимо, не понимаю просто, почему это принципиально", без этой фразы и не стал бы встревать. Впрочем, не смею настаивать.

Answer (score 0):

Что за привычка? Доев свое жаркое с подливкой, вытирать тарелку хлебом и съедать его. Это описание привычки включает в себя деепричастный оборот, который, по общему правилу, должен обособляться, т. е. нужны две запятые. Ни один из известных мне случаев, когда деепричастный оборот не обособляется, не подходит. 
Если (вдруг!) вы найдете причину не обособлять его, обе запятые нужно убрать. Ситуация с одной запятой кажется мне невозможной.

Comment: Спасибо! Хотелось бы ещё ответов. Очень не хочется почему-то считать выделение правильным.

Comment: Понимаю Вас. В самом деле, глаза "спотыкаются" о первую запятую, но формально не нахожу причин ее убрать. Может быть, кто-нибудь найдет.

Comment: Хотел Вам поставить плюсик — не вышло.( Убрали такую возможность для комментариев?

Comment: Я ее вижу (стрелка вверх появляется, если навести мышку на комментарий)

Comment: А-а, действительно, спасибо! Надо было просто навести)

Comment: Вот совершенно не понял, к чему тут рассуждения о привычках и их описании. Все содержательное -  "Ни один из случаев не подходит". Все, что до  и после - просто непонятно. Это - некая семантика, подобные рассуждения никак не могут быть применены для мотивации постановки запятой или оправдания её отсутствия.

Comment: @Morkovkin Согласен, убрал лишние рассуждения.

Answer (score 0):

> > Вообще фраза кривоватая

Чем кривоватая?

> > но тем не менее хочется понять, действительно ли нужны эти запятые.

Естественно, нужны. Обычный деепричастный оборот, к тому же довольно распространенный — в чем проблема? Здесь и в других подобных случаях хочется сказать: не надо мудрствовать! В чистом виде "синдром сверхграмотности", когда после чтения многочисленных справочников даже "мама мыла раму" начинает вызывать сомнения.

Answer (score 0):

> Запятые, которые у меня в скобках, были. Вообще фраза кривоватая, но
>   тем не менее хочется понять, действительно ли нужны эти запятые.

Да, нужны. По общему правилу обособления деепричастных оборотов. Согласен, что фраза кривоватая. Причина, думаю, в том, что деепричастие совершенного вида диссонирует основным глаголом совершенного "вытирать" - да еще в инфинитиве (сравните "уйдя, гасить свет" - по моему чудовищно). Но это не грамматическое соображение, стилистическое, формально запрета нет, иногда такое, наоборот, весьма выразительно и единственно возможно. Так что де-юре придраться нельзя. А по-другому тут и не скажешь, не меняя структуры фразы.

> Первую запятую совсем не хочется ставить, п. ч. идёт пояснение, что за
>   привычка.

А что за мотивация такая? Даже не могу вспомнить что-нибудь хоть отдаленное похожее  на логику "запятая не нужна потому, что далее следует пояснение...".

В любом случае запятые при обособлении (не только деепричастного оборота) всегда парные, если только одна из них не "поглощается" более сильным знаком (но никак не его отсутствием).

"Отменить" же обособление деепричастного оборота в целом можно только в нескольких случаях. Ссылку вам дали вполне употребимую (хотя и не авторитетную), я не буду повторяться.

> данный деепричастный оборот (со значением обстоятельства образа
>   действий)

Ну какое же это обстоятельство образа действия?! И какого действия? "Вытирать"?

Обстоятельство образа действия - это некая конструкция, выполняющая функции наречия. Деепричастия при этом как правило одиночные, реже - со словами, с которыми составляет единое смысловое целое (в примерах по ссылке - "откинув голову" без "головы" бессмысленно), как правило - несовершенного вида (исключение - смысловой продолженный перфект - действие "наклонив" сохраняется на момент основного действия...). По сути - наречие, выраженное другой частью речи (в данном случая - деепричастием).

Здесь же - вообще непонятно, откуда такая трактовка.

(+++)

Добавлю.
Споры о том, изменяется ли смысл при удалении "жаркого с подливкой" не актуальны. Ответ зависит от того, насколько реальны предположения, что герой мог поступать так только после жаркого, любого блюда или вообще вылизывал все тарелки, включая чужие.

Но каким бы ни был этот ответ, это не мотивация для отказа от запятой. Значения обстоятельства образа действия тут все равно не просматривается ни в одном случае.